# Angular CLI app not running when deploying to Linux App Service

Tags: linux, azure, azure-devops, angular-cli, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy an Angular CLI app to Azure App Service on Linux OS, using Azure Dev Ops - but no success. I get Image 1. No error in the server or application logs.

[image: Image 1]

This is what I done so far:

1. Built the Angular CLI app using DevOps Build and placed the resulted "dist" folder to the "drop" folder. See below (Image 2) the tasks that compose my build. This is working fine and creating the expected files.

[image: Image 2]

2. Created a release in DevOps, deploying all the dist files in the wwwroot folder in the Azure App Service in Linux. Shown below are both, the wwwroot folder (left) and my local dist folder (right) after I run a ng build --prod.

[image: Image 3]

I have the suspicion that I need to kickstart the angular by feeding some time of command when doing the deployment. I have tried running "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0" but that didn't work.

Comment: what are you talking about? this is an app building question not a networking one. there are thousands of questions similar to this one in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a subtle and big difference between the Linux and Windows App service: IIS - which in Windows is actively looking to serve any app, whereas in Linux you have to spin up something on your own to serve it - Express for example.

After some research I discovered that I don't need a full App service dedicated to run a static app (such as Angular or React). It can be done just as efficiently and much cheaper with something like Storage. -> https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/static-website/getting-started

Answer (score 9):

Check the Azure App Service > Linux section on this page.  Essentially, you have to serve the app.

Add `npx serve -s` in the App Service Configuration > General Settings > Startup Command

[image]

In addition to the Azure Web App setting (above), you can also execute the startup after a deployment.  If you are using Azure Pipelines, you'd kick it off with something like:

```yaml
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy website'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '[your Azure subscription]'
    appType: webAppLinux
    WebAppName: '[your Azure web app]'
    packageForLinux: '[artifacts]/package.zip'
    StartupCommand: 'npx serve -s'
```

*2023 UPDATE*: you no longer need to configure this with a `ecoysystem.config.js` PM2 file in the root directory, with this inside as originally answered.

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            script: "npx serve -s"
        }
    ]
};
```

Old reference: https://burkeholland.github.io/posts/static-site-azure

Comment: that does not seem to work anymore, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63660012/azure-app-service-suddenly-delivers-file-directory-overview-instead-of-angular-a

Comment: Mine still works with this setup
https://stock-charts.azurewebsites.net

Comment: You no longer need the PM2 file aspect in Azure.  I typically run it immediately after a deployment, but also have it in the Startup Command so it restarts automatically.

Answer (score 4):

I had to give the `npx serve -s` as the startup command[image]

Then set the `Runtime Stack` with node framework `10.16 (NODE|10.16)`. See below[image]

Then everything started working.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use App Service - Web App you can just the **Windows OS** instead of **Linux.**

Here are the parameters I Used:

[image]

Since the output of building angular is a static web app, IIS will serve the site right away.

Answer (score 1):

When using Linux App Service container, you may also select PHP stack containing Apache2 Server. Since, Angular files are static ones (JS, CSS, HTML), so you just need some web server to serve this content.

Example configuration: [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the default 'Deploy Node.js App to Azure App Service' release template, it uses the 'Deploy Azure App Service' task and adds the following commands to the task. this might help you out.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I discovered this was a necessary step when do you deployments to Windows based App Service. However, I don't think is necessary to include a web.config for Linux service.

Comment: oh right, the 'iisnode' part should have given it way to me *facepalm*. When using Linux it does seem the add "-WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION 6.9.1" to the App settings section. but apart from that i'm not seeing any interesting configuration being passes along

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Azure App Service with Linux and Node, solved it using below startup command

pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa

[image: Snapshot from my DevOps pipeline]

Comment: The deployment works fine, but I get a 404 after deployment