# Azure App Service suddenly delivers file directory overview instead of Angular App

Tags: node.js, angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App (WebAppLinux) running an Angular application. The deployment is based on the Azure WebApp@1 task in an Azure pipeline.

Everything was fine until today. Without anyone having done a deployment, the website only shows an index page with the files stored in the home directory.

A re-deployment through the CI/CD pipeline is still successful. However, the error remains.

Was there any change to the Azure App Service that made my application incompatible?

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707804/deployed-angular-app-to-azure-web-app-but-showing-the-default-azure-page ? If you use Linux app  you need to have webserver running your app. Did you do that?

Comment: We are facing the same problem. Could you find a solution?

Comment: @Mischa see my answer below

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55080947/angular-cli-app-not-running-when-deploying-to-linux-app-service/56590887#56590887

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer of LuisDev99 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61707805/3809334 has solved the problem.

We had to add

`pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa`

to the Startup Command under Configuration, select the tab -> General Settings

In the past we had a startup script that called `npx serve -s` within our Angular application.

It seems that this way did not work anymore over the weekend. Maybe because there was a configuration change in the WebApp by Microsoft

Comment: We had the same problem. We switched to an azure storage account to serve the static files.

Comment: This also worked for us, but this cannot be a long term solution imho, since web.config is now also being ignored, and we configured all our CSP headers inside web.config

Comment: this works, but same as @EimerReis we also put our custom headers in `web.config`. do you have any suggestions how can Linux App Service read the `web.config` specially the customer headers?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but if you file an issue in https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/Linux/issues, that will help proceed with the next steps for investigation.