# NestJs deployed to Azure Linux Web App wont start

Tags: linux, azure, nestjs

I have spent many days but still can not get this to work.

I have setup a deployment pipeline for NextJS I have the dist folder and I'm also copying the node modules folder etc. The build pipeline works, makes a package which is then deployed to a Azure Linux Web App.

Problem is can not hit the application

I look into the logs and I can see the app has started but for some reason the container fails and the site never works.

[image]

[image]

I'm pulling my hair out here I have tried everything, read every guide I can find but nothing seems to work. Help me stack-bi-wan-overflow your my only hope.

Comment: Update to this, I changed my configuration to use express instead of fastify and it now works. Fastify looks to have a different network configuration that the container can't connect too.

Answer (score 0):

As you have confirmed in your comment , Converting this to answer to help other community members.

***To achieve the above requirement make sure that you have used express instead of using fastify . As fastify must have different network configuration which can not connect with container.***

For more information please refer the below links:-

- SO THREAD: [***nestjs to azure windows app service - web.config settings***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232654/nestjs-to-azure-windows-app-service-web-config-settings?rq=1) & [***Angular CLI app not running when deploying to Linux App Service***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55080947/angular-cli-app-not-running-when-deploying-to-linux-app-service?rq=1)
- Blog:- [***Deploy and run Nest js app to azure***](https://scriptbytes.io/deploy-nestjs-api-to-linux-app-service-on-azure/)